# I am using this sql statement to delete the total record from a table

Tags: mysql

```
DELETE FROM Orders WHERE OrderID BETWEEN 1 AND 1000;
```

but if the table record is unknown to me than how can i delete all record from the table without deleting table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TRUNCATE Orders;
```

This is all what you need to delete all the content of your selected table

Answer (score 0):

DELETE

- When we have to use DELETE Command then the data deleted can be retrieved when you ROLLBACK.

> DELETE * FROM Orders;

TRUNCATE

- It drops the table and re-create it. It is much faster than deleting
  rows one by one. Once you use TRUNCATE command then you cannot retrieve
  the data again from the table.

> TRUNCATE Orders;

Answer (score 0):

Use "TRUNCATE" syntax.

It will empties a table completely.

Check this document:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all the records, you can do this with:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Orders
```

The table still exists but will be empty.

But if you want to delete a range of records you could probably do:

```
DELETE FROM Orders WHERE OrderID BETWEEN 1 AND (SELECT max(OrderID) FROM table)
```

In the last case all OrderID's must be unique.